How to pass env variables to vite.config for github pages
Hello folks quick question rose.
I'm deploying vite app to github pages. And this app should use proxy to the server. For dev deployments and surve all works fine but when I publish on gh pages seems like my config file not working.
here is example of my config file
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { nodePolyfills } from "vite-plugin-node-polyfills";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");

  return {
    plugins: [nodePolyfills(), react()],
    build: {
      outDir: "./dist",
    },
    base: env.VITE_BASE_URL || "/",
    publicDir: "./public",
    server: {
      port: 5173,
      proxy: {
        "/api": {
          target: env.VITE_BACKEND_URL, // Replace with your API's URL
          changeOrigin: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
          secure: false
        },
      },
    },
  };
});


and here is my yml file to deploy on gh pages
name: Deploy my app

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Pages
        id: pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
        with:
          static_site_generator: none

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 20
      - uses: oven-sh/setup-bun@v2
        with:
          bun-version: latest

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: bun install --frozen-lockfile

      - name: Debug environment
        run: |
          echo "Repository name: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}"
          echo "Base URL: /${{ github.event.repository.name }}"
          echo "Backend URL: ${{ secrets.VITE_BACKEND_URL }}"
          echo "Release name: ${{ secrets.VITE_RELEASE_NAME }}"
      - name: Build
        run: bun run build
        env:
          VITE_BASE_URL: /${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          VITE_ENV: production
          VITE_BACKEND_URL: ${{ secrets.VITE_BACKEND_URL }}
          VITE_RELEASE_NAME: ${{ secrets.VITE_RELEASE_NAME }}

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: ./dist

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2


I created secrets in gh pages but it doesn't seems helped. I can read them from the app by simply pronting in template {import.meta.env.VITE_RELEASE_NAME}. But I need use this variable in vite.config.ts. How to do that? I didn't find answers that suits my question here :(

Vite's proxy only runs with the dev server. Github pages only serves static content. You'll need to send requests directly to your backend

it is similar but the thing is my backend and front ent are hosted on different servers. so basically I need do request from site A to site B. thats Why I wanted to use proxy in production
